# Wrong size classes for iPad on Simulator (TraitCollection)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, size-classes, uitraitcollection

I have following code in my UIViewController:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    let horizontalSizeClass = traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass
    let verticalSizeClass = traitCollection.verticalSizeClass

    if horizontalSizeClass == .regular && verticalSizeClass == .regular {
        setConstraintsForiPad()
    } else if verticalSizeClass == .compact {
        setConstraintsForLandscape()
    } else if horizontalSizeClass == .compact && verticalSizeClass == .regular {
        setConstraintsForPortrait()
    }
}
```

I want to detect iPad from this method - I've read that iPad should have both size classes set to 'regular', but as it turns out app running on simulator sets size classes to regular-compact respectively. Why is that so? Thanks for help.

Comment: iPad in split view will have a width of compact. Outside of that you need to give more information. E.g. which virtual device, what orientation, does it update after initial load to the expected values, are you using the free-form simulator.

Comment: For anyone else, this might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015145-CH13